# What is the term that describes a group of animals; gaggle of geese, murder of crows

Tags: meaning

I'm looking for the term, word and or phrase that describes groups of animals. I'd like to know all the words that refer to all groups of animals.

Comment: See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28841/what-is-the-collective-noun-for-a-collection-of-collective-nouns/28844#28844).

Comment: Terms like: murder of crows and gaggle of geese interest me and I'd like to know the whole list of terms that describe other groups.

Comment: They're called **venereal terms**. See James Lipton, [_An Exaltation of Larks_](http://books.google.com/books/about/An_exaltation_of_larks.html?id=8a_0tZp--EMC)